# html 5 function not executed?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working through a book called "Beginning Facebook Game Apps Dev" and in Chapter 3 they introduce us to create code for html document.

I'm on a Mac and I use TextEdit to create the pages. At first the book gave code to draw a rectangle and a triangle. Both were fine but then I try the code rotation, it only displays the box.

I have been programming for some time now with c++ without being an expert but I know absolutely nothing yet on how the internet works. Anyway the only difference I can see between the code that works and the one that doesn't is the fact to rotate I call functions where for the rectangle I dont. Could anyone tell me what is going on please?

ps: I tried to google html 5 function not working but honestly I'm at a loss for words on how to search for this specific problem.

thank you

***code working (draw rectangle)***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta    name="viewport"    content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <title>A simple Canvas Square</title>
    <style type="text/css"    media="screen">
    #canvas
    {
        border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="270" height="270"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript"    charset="utf-8">

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.fillStyle = "gray";
        context.fillRect(30, 30, 200, 200);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***code not working (rotation)***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta   http-equiv="content-type"   content="text/html;  charset=utf-8">

    <title>overlapping box</title>
    <style type="text/css"    media="screen">
    #canvas
    {
        border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript"    charset="utf-8">
        function draw(canvas Id)
        {
        "use strict";
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.fillStyle = "#091F5D";
        context.fillRect(10, 10, 160, 150);

        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 78, 0, 0.5)";
        context.fillRect(90, 90, 160, 150);

        context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 78, 0)";
        context.fillRect(170, 160, 160, 150);
        }

        draw('canvas');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

in this line:

```
function draw(canvas Id)
```

you should not have a space between the words 'canvas' and 'Id'.  Change it to:

```
function draw(canvasId)
```

`canvasId` is the name of the parameter (with the value passed being the id of the canvas element in which you want to draw the rectangles).

Comment: youre my hero. It solved the problem of this code but also all the codes provided by the book. (eventhough the i didn't put a space between canvas and Id for the other codes, it was still a problem of putting a space)

Comment: If this solved the problem, please remember to show your appreciation by accepting the answer (just below the voting part).